# how to change name in form month

Tags: cakephp, datepicker, cakephp-3.0

I have this in my code

```
$this->Form->month('cc_month',['monthNames' => false]);
```

It generates the following code:

```
<select name="cc_month[month]">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="01">1</option>
    <option value="02">2</option>
    <option value="03">3</option>
    <option value="04">4</option>
    <option value="05">5</option>
    <option value="06">6</option>
    <option value="07">7</option>
    <option value="08">8</option>
    <option value="09">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

But I only want `<select name="cc_month">`, without the `[month]` prefix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method

```
Cake\View\Helper\FormHelper::month(string $fieldName, array $attributes)
```

is meant to be used with `date` related fields.

The property `$fieldName` will be used as a prefix for the HTML name attribute of the select element, as described in [Creating Date & Time Related Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-date-time-related-controls).

In your case, I understand that field `month` stores an integer. You can use the following code to generate the appropriate `SELECT` tag:

```
echo $this->Form->select('cc_month',range(1,12))
```